# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function save() on null in admin\propiedades\actualizar.php:54 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown on line 54

Tags: php, fileupload

> Me lanza este error y no se que hacer, por que al actualizar la img está en la BD pero no en el formulario y si quiero actualizar si modificar la imagen me deberia tirar un error de que hay que colocar una pero me tira este error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function save() on null in admin\propiedades\actualizar.php:54 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown on line 54.

```
?php
        use App\Propiedad;
        use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;        
        require '../../includes/app.php';           
        estaAutenticado();
    
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $id = filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
  
        if(!$id) {
            header('Location: /admin');
        }
    
        $propiedad = Propiedad::find($id);
    
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM vendedores";
    
        $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $consulta);
    
        $errores = Propiedad::getErrores();
                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            $args = $_POST['propiedad'];
            
            $propiedad->sincronizar($args);
            
            $nombreImagen = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . ".jpg";

            if ($_FILES['propiedad']['tmp_name']['imagen']) {
                $image = Image::make($_FILES['propiedad']['tmp_name']['imagen'])->fit(800, 600);
                $propiedad->setImagen($nombreImagen);    
            }
    
            $errores = $propiedad->validar();
    
            if (empty($errores)) {
                // Almacenar la imagen
                $image->save(CARPETA_IMAGENES . $nombreImagen);
    
                $propiedad->guardar();
            }
    }     
<main class="contenedor seccion">
    <h1>Actualizar Propiedad</h1>

    <a href="/admin" class="boton boton-amarillo">Volver</a>

    <?php foreach ($errores as $error) : ?>
        <div class="alerta error">
            <?php echo $error; ?>

        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <form class="formulario" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- enctype="multipart/form-data": hay que habilitar esto en el formulario para el backend -->
        
        <!-- Incluimos el formulario -->
        <?php include '../../includes/templates/formulario_propiedades.php'; ?>

        <input type="submit" value="Actualizar Propiedad" class="boton boton-verde">
    </form>
</main>
```

Comment: Si esta es la línea `54` en tu código: `$image->save(CARPETA_IMAGENES . $nombreImagen);` parece que `$image` es `null` en tu contexto. Depura ese objeto poniendo un `var_dump($image);` y dinos qué muestra. Si es `null` debes verificar qué está ocurriendo con la creación de tu imagen.

Comment: Si me tira NULL

Comment: Pero la imagen ya está creada nose porque me dice que está null

Comment: ¿Creada dónde? ¿Cómo la creas y por qué dices que está creada?

Comment: Porque ese codigo es del arhivo para actualizar las propiedades y luego tengo otro para crear que es donde crea una carpeta en el servidor y tambien en la DB

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que hace esto: `$image = Image::make($_FILES['propiedad']['tmp_name']['imagen'])->fit(800, 600);`? En esa llamada `$image` está resultado `null` y tienes que verificar el motivo. Activa **temporalmente** la muestra de errores en pantalla: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` luego guarda sl archivo e intenta de nuevo y dinos qué errores hay en pantalla.